# Can I pass a multidimensional array through route laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array, routes

1. This is the form which contains a button that sends the post, and through which I send the multidimensional array called $equipos

   ```
     <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 65%;">
       <form action="{{route('codigos_barra.create', $equipos)}}" class="form-inline" method="POST">
           <button class="btn btn-primary shadow" type="submit">
               <i class="fas fa-qrcode"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Generar QR
           </button>
       </form>
   </div>
   ```
2. This is the route

   ```
   Route::get('codigos_barra/create/{equipos}', 'CodigoBarraController@create')->name('codigos_barra.create')->middleware('auth','roles:1');
   ```
3. This is the error

   > Missing required parameters for [Route: codigos_barra.create] [URI: codigos_barra/create/{equipos}]. (View: C:\laragon\www\pmei\resources\views\equipos\codigos_barra\index.blade.php)

Comment: I think you should give only ID or some unique parameter to your route. Could you pls paste dd($equipos)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, it's not related to laravel or even PHP. It's just how you send arrays variables via HTML.

You must be familiar with the one dimension array `<input name="arrayName[]" />`, You can also give an index to your variable

```html
<input type="hidden" name="equipos[0][0]" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="equipos[0][1]" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="equipos[0][2]" value="3" />
<input type="hidden" name="equipos[1][0]" value="4" />
<input type="hidden" name="equipos[1][1]" value="5" />
<input type="hidden" name="equipos[1][2]" value="6" />
<input type="hidden" name="equipos[2][0]" value="7" />
<input type="hidden" name="equipos[2][1]" value="8" />
<input type="hidden" name="equipos[2][2]" value="9" />
```

These inputs will send the array `equipos` as

```
equipose => | 1  2  3 |

            | 4  5  6 |

            | 7  8  9 |
```

In your controller, you can recover it as any other input

```php
$equipos = request()->input('equipos', []);
// or
$equipos = request()->get('equipos');
```

**Another solution** would be to convert your array to json and `json_decode()` it in the controller

```html
<input type="hidden" name="equipos_json" value="{{json_encode($equipos)}}" />
```

```php
$equipos = json_decode(request()->input('equipos', ''), true);
```